# Simulate Network Latency mac Sierra

Tags: macos

I am trying to simulate network latency for all traffic to a certain ip/url.  I tried using a proxy through Charles but the traffic is going through HTTP or SOCKS.  I found some information online but it does not seem to work for me.  Can anyone see what is wrong with my commands?

```
#enable pf
pfctl -E

#add a temporary extra ruleset (called "anchor") named "deeelay
(cat /etc/pf.conf && echo "dummynet-anchor \"deeelay\"" && echo "anchor 
 \"deeelay\"") | sudo pfctl -f -

#add a rule to the deeelay set to send any traffic to endpoint through new rule
echo "dummynet out proto tcp from any to myurl.com pipe 1" | 
sudo pfctl -a deeelay -f -

#Add a rule to dummynet pipe 1 to delay every packet by 500ms
sudo dnctl pipe 1 config delay 500
```

I see this warning when I run the commands:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the proto parameter.  The application is not using tcp, it is using another protocol.  You can either supply all the protocols you want as a list like so:

```
proto { tcp udp icmp ipv6 tlsp smp }
```

Or you can just remove the proto parameter altogether and it will do all protocols.